# Is there a way to fetch all DocumentDb resoruces from Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

My goal is to fetch all the resources from the azure to our local database. I've been able to fetch various types of resources (virtual machines, websites, storage accounts etc.) using C# SDK (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net). However, it seems there's no wrapper for DocumentDb resource, what's more, I can't event find an endpoint to query it. Do you know how to fetch all DocumentDb resources ?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728142/exporting-data-from-azure-documentdb) SO question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier - I don't think the OP is talking about extracting data from the database; just the info about their resources.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'd like to fetch all information about my DocumentDb resources. Generally, see the subset of information available in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this powershell cmdlet

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work exactly as expected, which is kind of weird. If I run this

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
```

It outputs all the storage accounts. Go figure...

edit:
Yes it is working fine. I was looking in the wrong subscription for docDbs... idiot.

As for doing it with REST, @macpak I haven't done it myself, but I suspect you could do something like:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/yourSubId/resourceGroups/yourResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts?api-version=2016-03-31
```

This is how https://resources.azure.com works, check it out. Obviously you parameterise the subId and RGname and build the URI. You would also need to get a bearer token and put it in the authorisation header. Use postman and/or fiddler..

Comment: Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" is working for me.

Comment: Is there a way to use C# (REST API) to get the same information ?