# Easy way to download a Cosmos DB from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, database-backups

I don't find how to download it. I'd like to do it for 2 reasons:

- Backup it to my computer
- Try to open it with Microsoft Excel

However, I don't find an easy way like clicking on a button to download it.

The only way seems to code a complex piece of code to go throw the whole database and export it in some format like JSON.

Am I right? Hopefully you found an easy way to download the database from Azure!

We clicked here:

[image: screenshot]

But that csv doesn't contain any data, just information about databases

Comment: You're correct, in that Cosmos DB does not have an "export database" feature. There are tools (such as the database migration tool) and services (such as data factory) you can take advantage of, to export data of your choosing, or you can write code to do something specific to your needs, perhaps based on changefeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool for that purpose. You can download it [here](https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/data-migration-desktop-tool/releases), and it's got a simple UI for both importing and exporting data. I find it quite a bit easier than Data Factory. And since it runs locally on Windows, it also works with the Cosmos DB Emulator.

Comment: unfortunately the provided [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) does not work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

You could use Azure Data Factory and export your data e.g. to Blob Storage in CSV format. should be very easy to build with the copy wizard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool

The Export to CSV button that you showed above does only export the table of resources in the Azure Portal, it has nothing to do with Cosmos DB or even the data inside it.

Comment: I'd suggest not calling any solution "easy" . Agreed that ADF is a potential solution for the OP.

Comment: the copy data tool is really mostly a code-free exercise. So unless he has a very complex data model in Cosmos, it should indeed be fairly easy

Comment: My point being "easy" is relative, and when someone is learning something new, it's not necessarily easy for them until it's learned. Maybe for someone already comfortable with the service and its usage and nuances.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an EASY way in azure tools, so I use compass to export data as json for mongoDB collections and I call it EASY.